# passing a function in df.insert

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame say,

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I need to create a data frame with the help of a function like,

```
Var_name Count Max 
A        3      7
B        3      8
C        3      9
```

What I tried is ,

```
def DQ_Function():

    data=load_file_us._get_numeric_data()
    num_cols=data.columns  
    count1=data.count()

    df=pd.DataFrame(num_cols,columns=['Var_Name']) # create new dataframe from num_columns  
    df.insert(1,'Count',count1)
    return df
DQ_Function()
```

But it returns 'NaN' values in the df. Kindly let me know where I am gone wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
count1=data.count()
count1

A    3
B    3
C    3
dtype: int64
```

`count1` is series having ABC as index.
and `df` is dataframe having 012 as index.
So to use `df.insert`:

```py
def DQ_Function():

    data=load_file_us._get_numeric_data()
    num_cols=data.columns  
    count1 = df.count().reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index.

    df=pd.DataFrame(num_cols,columns=['Var_Name']) # create new dataframe from num_columns  
    df.insert(1,'Count',count1)
    return df

DQ_Function()
```

Comment: where is the max here?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).

```
new_df = df.agg(['count','max']).T.rename_axis(index = 'Var_name').reset_index()
print(new_df)
  Var_name  count  max
0        A      3    7
1        B      3    8
2        C      3    9
```

So I will use this **function**:

```
def DQ_Function(df):
    return (df.agg(['count','max'])
              .T
              .rename_axis(index = 'Var_name')
              .reset_index()
              .rename(columns = {'count':'Count','max':'Max'})
           )
print(DQ_Function(df)) 

#  Var_name  Count  Max
#0        A      3    7
#1        B      3    8
#2        C      3    9
```

**Alternative**

```
def DQ_Function(df):
    return (df.count()
              .to_frame('Count')
              .join(df.max()
                      .to_frame('Max'))
              .rename_axis('Var_Name')
              .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9]})

# collect results
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Var_name','Count','Max'])
for column in df:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Var_name':[column], 'Count': [df[column].shape[0]],'Max': [df[column].max()]})
    results = results.append(df2)
```

Results:

```
  Var_name Count Max
0        A     3   7
0        B     3   8
0        C     3   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
def DQ_Function(df):

    df1 = pd.concat([df.count(), df.max()], axis=1).reset_index()
    df1.columns = ['Var_name','Count', 'Max']
    return df1

print(DQ_Function(df))

  Var_name  Count  Max
0        A      3    7
1        B      3    8
2        C      3    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one line solution by using [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [df.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,4],'B':[5,8,9],'C':[7,1,3]})
df.melt(var_name="Var_Names", value_name="Value").groupby(['Var_Names']).agg({'Value': ['count', 'max'], })
```